# issues of 'this' in a library like selector prototype

Tags: javascript, function, pipe, this

What I want to make?
$(arguments).sample(function(){ return this; })

- a selector like above mentioned and then prototype it with a function named sample and in that call a function
- if users use 'this'; that should return the arguments objects

What I did?

```
var $ = function(){
    return new library();
}
var library = function(){};
library.prototype = {
 sample: function(callback) {
  callback();
 }
}
```

but not able to do what I want to do actually :/
I tried a lot of things, but I want $ to be both usable as a function `$([1,2]).stringify()` (about which I have been talking about) and an object like mentioned above `$.sample()`

Some possible examples:

```
$('hello').print();
$('hello').sample(function(){ console.log(this); });
$.print('hello');
$('hello').print().log();
```

Comment: You're using `sample` both from `library.prototype` and also from `$`. Are you sure you really want to do that?

Comment: urh, yeah I suppose, that gives me more freedom to work and then update the code if in case, necessary

Comment: This sounds like a very strange design. While there are use-cases for functions having functions on them (jQuery does that), they aren't the *same* functions, they're different ones. I think you'll have to explain more thoroughly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: If you really want the same functions in two different places (which I agree is a very odd design), then you can put all the functions in one of the places, then just create a loop to iterate through that list and copy them to a second object.   I still think you're probably barking up the wrong tree on the design though.  Methods should either be instance methods or static methods, not both.

Comment: @jfriend00 I was kind of trying to prototype the jQuery build, i mean in quite an exciting way, they have done a lot so yeah!! perhaps in that case jquery's design is also odd if I am not wrong, I am eager to learn more about this!! so what could be done to achieve that!!

Comment: jQuery has static methods on the `$` object and instance methods on the protototype.  The static methods do different things and take different arguments than the instance methods.  In some cases, an instance method calls a static method and passes it the data (from the instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- what if argument is a primitive. this can't be a primitive.+
- you can add a function to the prototype and as a utility-method, but the utility-method has to be a wrapper.
- if the proto-method is sth like this:

  $.prototype.foo = function(arg1, arg2, arg3){
      for(var i=0; i

what should be the signature of the utility-method? how to separate the args of "this" and the function-args?

```
$.foo = function(...thisArg, arg1, arg2, arg3){}
//or
$.foo = function(thisArgs, arg1, arg2, arg3){}
//and what if thisArgs contains only one Array, are you sure, that you will remember/want to use [[/* values */]]
```

maybe you want to build sth like this:

```
function $(){
    var me = Object.create($.prototype);
    for(var i=0, j=arguments.length; i<j; ++i) me[i] = arguments[i];
    me.length = j;
    //Object.freeze(me);
    return me;
}

var AP = [];
$.prototype.reduce = AP.reduce;
$.prototype.each = function(fn){
    AP.forEach.call(this, fn, this);
    return this;
}

$.prototype.map = function(fn){
    return $.apply(null, AP.map.call(this, fn, this));
}

$.prototype.filter = function(fn){
    return $.apply(null, AP.filter.call(this, fn, this));
}

$.prototype.log = function(comment){
    if(comment) console.log(comment + ":");
    return this.each(v=>console.log("  ", v));
}
```

and the usage

```
var a = $("lorem", "ipsum", "dolor");
a.map((v,i) => i + ": " + v).log("logged Items");

console.log("a instanceof $: ", a instanceof $);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet.

```
   var library = { 
     sample: function(callback) { 
       callback(); 
     }
   };
   var $ = function(){
      return library;
   };

   for (var method in library) {
     if (library.hasOwnProperty(method) && typeof library[method] == 'function') {
       $[method] = library[method].bind(library);
     }
   }
```

Comment: for 100 functions, I don't think that's legitimate enough to do; it would make code very long; any alternative? and does this solve the this issue and could be reusable for all the situations listed?

Comment: In any case, Parth said he wanted it on `$`, not `library`.

Comment: `$('hello').sample(function(){ console.log(this) })` still returns a window object while I thought it could give me 'hello' or perhaps any argument :/ Please help!!